# Python UDP listener not returning data recieved from an MT4000 telemetry device. Ubuntu

Tags: python, udp, telemetry

I have:

- Set up an MT4000, which is broadcasting data every 30s
- Done a tcpdump in terminal to watch the data coming in, so I know it is being sent
- Written a UDP listener in Python (code here --> https://gist.github.com/edprince/5a7c87771435b9631656 )

At the moment when I run this, it successfully creates the socket, and binds the host and port, but then it doesn't display any data. No error is displayed, just a black screen, even when I watch the packets being received in the tcpdump. I am just trying to narrow down to where the problem is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code lets the socket listen at localhost/`127.0.0.1` which is most probably not the interface receiving packets from external hardware.  Either listen on the specific interface or on all interfaces with `0.0.0.0`.